# Mixing Vue with Razor Page Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, vuejs3, vue-component, razor-pages

I am struggling to understand how to pass my c# Model to a Vue component (compo API).

Here is my Model:

```
namespace myProject.Models{
    public class Card{
        public Image Image{ get; set; }  
        public string Title{ get; set; }  
        public string Date{ get; set; }  
        public string Paragraph{ get; set; }  
        public Link Link { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Here is my .cshtml.cs:

```
        Cards = new List<Card>{
            new Card{Title="Card Title1", Image= new Image{Src="ddddd", Alt="sssss"}, Date="Date here", Link= new Link{Text="ggg", Url="/"}},
            new Card{Title="Card Title2", Image= new Image{Src="ddddd", Alt="sssss"}, Date="Date here", Link= new Link{Text="dddg", Url="/"}},
            new Card{Title="Card Title3", Image= new Image{Src="ddddd", Alt="sssss"}, Date="Date here", Link= new Link{Text="gggggaa", Url="/"}}    
        };
```

Here is my .cshtml:

```
@foreach (var card in Model.Cards){  
   <Card card="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@card)"></Card>
}
```

And inside my component:

```
<template>
   {{ card }} //renders as a string
   {{ card.Title }} //renders nothing
</template>

<script setup>    
  const props = defineProps({card: Object});
</script>
```

I obviously don't understand, but what I am expecting is to have the "card" prop be a converted Array or Object within in vue file. But its *always* a String, which means I cannot loop over/read the data (loops results in looping each character in the String)

I have tried using v-bind like so:

```
@foreach (var card in Model.Cards){  
   <Card :card="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@card)"></Card>
}
```

But this renders `[object, Object]`, and I am unsure how to deal with those.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

A fix seems to be parsing the string inside the vue component itself:

```
const props = defineProps({brochures: Object});    
const parsedModel = ref(JSON.parse(props.brochures));
```

Then I can loop over parsedModel just fine. I am not sure if this is the best fix, but if anyone else is in this situation, this is how I got around it.
If anyone knows better, please advise.